# HTML link not working--this shouldn't be difficult

Tags: html, href

This was a perfectly functioning page with links to samples of work.  I added some XML work and that link will not function.  I can't figure out why.  I apologize if it's something obvious.  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <center>
            <a href="C++/index.html"><div class="friend"><p>C++</p></div></a>
            <a href="SQL/index.html"><div class="family"><p>SQL</p></div></a>
            <a href="OS/index.html"><div class="enemy"><p>OS</p></div></a>
            <a href-"XML/index.html"><div class="friend"><p>XML</p></div></a>
            <a href="Miscellaneous/index.html"><div class="family"><p>Miscellaneous</p></div></a>
            <a href="http://github.com/"><div class="enemy"><p>GitHub</p></div></a>




        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the stylesheet:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

div p {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.friend {
    border: 4px solid green;
}

.family {
    border: 4px solid blue;
}

.enemy {
    border: 4px solid red;
}

a:hover
{ 
background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Comment: This isn't your actual issue, but you should use `margin` and/or `text-align` styles in place of your `<br>`s (because that's more semantically correct) and `<center>` (because that tag is deprecated).

Comment: this is a typo problem. you should check your code more before post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a typo in your href tag on the XML line.

```
            <a href-"XML/index.html"><div class="friend"><p>XML</p></div></a>
```

should be

```
            <a href="XML/index.html"><div class="friend"><p>XML</p></div></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

This  `<a href="XML/index.html"><div>` and not `<a href-"XML/index.html"><div>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href-"XML...
```

should be

```
<a href="XML...
```

Also, your code could use some fixes (your string of br's makes me cringe!)

Answer (score 1):

Change it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <center>
            <a href="C++/index.html"><div class="friend"><p>C++</p></div></a>
            <a href="SQL/index.html"><div class="family"><p>SQL</p></div></a>
            <a href="OS/index.html"><div class="enemy"><p>OS</p></div></a>
            <a href="XML/index.html"><div class="friend"><p>XML</p></div></a><!-- You have used here a "-" instead of a "=" -->
            <a href="Miscellaneous/index.html"><div class="family"><p>Miscellaneous</p></div></a>
            <a href="http://github.com/"><div class="enemy"><p>GitHub</p></div></a>




        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here was the problem, you've made a **-** instead of a **=**:

```
<a href-"XML/index.html">....
```

Comment: You should indicate what the change was, rather than making the OP hunt for it and potentially miss it, since that's basically the same problem when the typo was initially made.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a div into a  tag. Give the a tag a class instead.

Comment: HTML5 now allows block-level elements inside of `<a>` elements.